# How to add value to an array and remove it if it's already in with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a multi-filter and I am having difficulty with the JS code.
It is necessary add category attr into the array when clicking, and deleted from it when it is clicked again.

Here is my code that is not working correctly.

```js
$('span[data-genre]').click(function(event) {

  var genre = [];
  var category = $(this).attr('data-genre');

  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    var removeItem = $(this).attr('data-genre');
    genre = $.grep(genre, function(value) {
      return value != removeItem;
    });

    alert(genre);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    genre.push($(this).attr('data-genre'));
    alert(genre);
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span:hover {
  color: green;
}

.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-genre="1">1</span>
<span data-genre="2">2</span>
<span data-genre="3">3</span>
<span data-genre="4">4</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move `var genre = [];` outside the `click` event.

Since it's inside your `click` event, then it will reset every time you click on an object

**Demo**

```js
var genre = [];
$('span[data-genre]').click(function(event) {

  var category = $(this).attr('data-genre');

  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    var removeItem = $(this).attr('data-genre');
    genre = $.grep(genre, function(value) {
      return value != removeItem;
    });

    console.log(genre);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    genre.push($(this).attr('data-genre'));
    console.log(genre);
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span:hover {
  color: green;
}

.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-genre="1">1</span>
<span data-genre="2">2</span>
<span data-genre="3">3</span>
<span data-genre="4">4</span>
```

Comment: Good eye, beat me to it.